# Should I have a fourth recommender in PhD Application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

Due to some technical issues, it took me a couple of weeks to hear back from one of my potential recommendation writers for my Business PhD application.  I reached out to other reviewers in the interim and have filled all of my required slots.  I just heard back from the first person, and I am wondering if I should add a fourth letter for a few schools.  I think this professor can add some unique perspective since I traveled with her for a two week immersion elective and the experience informed the topics I would like to research.  Will the additional  perspective be helpful?  Or will a fourth letter just indicate that I didn't pay attention to the requirements or was worried about the strength about my other letters?

Answer (score 1):

Provide the number of letters of recommendation requested.

Some systems will not allow you to add additional ones. Even if they do, I agree with the assessment that adding further letters won't reflect well. Either you didn't follow the rules, or you didn't figure out who'd be your best recommenders.

Comment: Also some schools (including ones I've worked at) will just toss extra letters, etc without consideration. You're just giving the admin more work to do, plus you won't know which ones were filed in the wastepaper basket.